# Issue when editing a Users Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm following a Book which shows you how to edit a users role. Everything's working fine until I get to a line of code. I think it will be a pretty simple solution, however, I cannot figure it out.

```
var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id,
                    selectedRole.Except(userRoles).ToArray<string>());
```

The line of code above is returning an error:

> "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'"

In the book, it shows:

```
.ToArray<string>
```

However, in my line of code, it's just telling me to refactor to:

```
.ToArray());
```

Is there another way of converting to string? I'll post the code below, thanks.

EDIT USER CODE

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditUser(EditUserViewModel model, params string[]  selectedRole)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }

                user.UserName = model.UserName;
                user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                user.LastName = model.LastName;

                var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

                selectedRole = selectedRole ?? new string[] { };

                var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id,
                    selectedRole.Except(userRoles).ToArray<string>()); // may not be right

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                    return View();
                }

                result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user.Id, userRoles.Except(selectedRole).ToArray().ToString()); // put to string

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                    return View();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something's failed.");
            return View();


        }
```

EditUserViewModel

```
public class EditUserViewModel
    {

            public string Id { get; set; }


            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Username")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "First Name")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string LastName { get; set; }


            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesList { get; set; }


    }
```

EditUser View

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Roles", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <span class="col-md-10">
            @foreach (var item in Model.RolesList)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRole" value="@item.Value"
                       checked="@item.Selected" class="checkbox-inline" />

                       @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
            }

          </span>
       </div>
```

Comment: It could be a typo. I think it should have been **AddToRolesAsync** (notice the 's'). That takes an IEnumerable<string> as second parameter.

Comment: Ah yes it was, thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to be able to help. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to string you can use [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Object___) and as a separator use 
string.Empty, null or whatever separator you want but will be included in your string.

```
string str = string.Join(string.Empty, yourArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It was a slight spelling mistake as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo in the book or when copying from the book. It should be:

```cs
var result = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id,
                selectedRole.Except(userRoles).ToArray<string>());
```

The `AddToRolesAsync` takes an `IEnumerable<string>` as its second parameter, `AddToRoleAsync` takes a string.